# extend/cast existing instance of model in backbone to be an instance of derived model (like casting in java)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, web

I have a problem extending already existing instances of models to other type of derived model in backbone, is that possible? 
if so, this is an example of what I need to do, please help:

I have a problem extending already existing instances of models to other type of derived model in backbone, is that possible? 
if so, this is an example of what I need to do, please help:

```
var A = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function(options){
        console.log('A initialized');
    },
    foo : function(){
        console.log('foo of A');
    }
});

var B = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function(options){
        A.prototype.initialize.apply(this, [options]);
        console.log('B initialized');
    },
    foo : function(){
        console.log('foo of B');
    },
    goo : function(){
        console.log('goo of B');
    }
});

var ACollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: A
});

var BCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: B
});

var aa = new ACollection();
var bb = new BCollection();

aa.add(new A({
    attr1:1,
    attr2:2,
    attr3:3
})); // **A initialized**

// later after a while

var a = aa.at(0);
var b = cast a to type B    <---- how to do this

bb.add(b);

// later after a while

console.log(bb.at(0).get('attr1')); // **1**
b.goo(); // **goo of B**
b.foo(); // **foo of B**

a.set({attr1:'new1'});
console.log(bb.at(0).get('attr1')); // **new1**
```

I don't want to clone the model 'a', because I may change attributes of 'a' elsewhere, and I want to see that also 'b' changed (the same object)
thanks
I don't want to clone the model 'a', because I may change attributes of 'a' elsewhere, and I want to see that also 'b' changed (the same object)
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do:

```
var a = ACollection.at(0);
var b = new B(a.toJSON()); // create a B instance with data from instance a?
```

If you want to add it to `bb` collection just:

```
bb.create(a.toJSON()); // executes  new B() internally
```

Comment: thanks @T J, but it is not what I want. I want 'a' to be the same object as 'b'. so when I change attribute in 'a', then all the handlers of this change will be triggered even if they defined on 'b'. as said earlier in my question ('b' is the same object of 'a').

Comment: @saleemdiab `a` and `b` can't be different things and the same object at the same time. that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

How about using _.extend?

Something like:

```
var AModel = Backbone.Model.extend(...);
var BModel = Backbone.Model.extend(...);

var a = new AModel();

_.extend(a, BModel.prototype);
```

I tried this out in a fiddle and it *seems to work alright*.

Calling `a.foo()` resulted in `foo of b` in my console. I quickly tested it out with events as well and they seemed to stay intact. There may be side effects that I have missed.